# How to convert JSON string into integer in python?

Tags: python, json

How can I convert year and isbn into integers from this json?

```
({
    "title": "The Notebook",
    "author": "Nicholas Sparks",
    "year": "1996",
    "isbn": "0553816713"
})
```

Comment: With the parentheses around it, it is not valid JSON.

Comment: you should not change the isbn to an integer, as it starts with a 0. it could lead to loss of data and cause issues where multiple books could get the same isbn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp), it is about json and Python!

This will work:

```
import json

json_data =  '''{
    "title": "The Notebook",
    "author": "Nicholas Sparks",
    "year": "1996",
    "isbn": "0553816713"
}'''

python_data = json.loads(json_data)

year = int(python_data["year"])
isbn  = int(python_data["isbn"])
print(year, isbn)
```

`json_data` is a string containing the data in json format. Then, with `json.loads()` is converted into a Python dictionary. Finally, `year` and `isbn` are being converted from string to integer.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply update the values with their corresponding int values

```
data = {
    "title": "The Notebook",
    "author": "Nicholas Sparks",
    "year": "1996",
    "isbn": "0553816713"
    }

data["year"] = int(data["year"])
data["isbn"] = int(data["isbn"])

print(data)

OUT: {'title': 'The Notebook', 'author': 'Nicholas Sparks', 'year': 1996, 'isbn': 553816713}
```