# Why is the API's POST call failing to post the data due to incompatible data types?

Tags: python, post, get

I'm currently working on a small project, and I'm stuck on posting a JSON object to my API using Python. How do I fix this? I don't quite understand the problem. The error says the expected value of type number got a string instead, but I don't know how to fix this.

I am not providing the API link due to security reasons.

Get method

```
import json
import requests


def get_response():
    api_url = "url_link"
    response = requests.get(api_url).json()
    submission_url = response['submissionUrl']
    sheets = json.dumps(response['sheets'])

    return submission_url, sheets
```

Post method

```
def post_response():
    api_url, results = get_response()
    email = "randomemail@gmail.com"
    myobj = {"email": email, "results": json.loads(results)}
    post_data = requests.post(api_url, json=myobj)
    post_data.json()
    return post_data.text


print(post_response())
```

This is the error code

```
{"reports":[{"id":"0","ok":true},{"id":"1","ok":true},{"id":"2","error":"invalid result: invalid cell B1: expected value of type number, got string"}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON numeric fields are numbers.  The most essential characteristic is that they should not be quoted.

Check your results from:  requests.get(api_url).json()

Are the numeric values quoted?  You could use a tool like *jsonschema* to help you validate them.  You could also use Python to break up each value in the dumped json and replace it, see this answer:  [How to convert JSON string into integer in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62115001/how-to-convert-json-string-into-integer-in-python)